# PHP - Alternating email selection based on a set schedule

Tags: php, email, logic, class-design

Ok, Here is the situation, I am looking for some general input on the logic of this class. The purpose of this class is to: query a schedule database for employees that are currently working, and select the email address of one person who is currently working.

This class gets called by procmail every time an email is received, and serves procmail one email to forward to.

When there is more than one person working, the 2nd email received should go to the next person, the third email to the next, and loop over them as such - Delivering them equally.
If nobody is working at a specific time, the list of active workers is set to everybody working the next day, or the same day respectively.

I have this class half-made, and I'm having a hard time coming up with the logic of equal delivery. I figure I would log each email sent in a database table, limit it to about 10 entries and just email it to the person who shows up the least. However, this will not be exactly equal.  Neither would just selecting a random email.

I'm not looking for someone to code this for me, just looking for some input on a better logic method; maybe someone has run into this kind of situation before?

The table design is extremely simple, it goes like:

date | name | email | time_in | time_out

Of course there are other tables that handle manual overrides, and the table I mentioned about logging sent emails. I can post the current class I have, but like I said it is half-made, and the class logic is pretty simple - other than this specific part.

Any Idea, or input is welcome!

Comment: Why not record all emails sent? You can empty the table on a daily basis if you're concerned about space.

Comment: Yes, but the context of the selection has to only be based on active workers. I don't want all emails delivered equally always - some employees work more often, less often, etc. The person that works less often would get inundated with emails when they log on wouldn't they?

Comment: Sure, base it on whatever other data you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about -- keep a counter of how many emails each person got, sort by least to determine who gets the next, then reset all the counters to zero at the start of each shift.

Comment: People have different shifts every day, may start at 8am, 11 am, 2pm... How exactly would I make a script to empty the tables based on a changing schedule, that runs automatically?  Maybe I could just track the number of active people when the last email was sent, and if that number changes the next time, truncate the counters?

Comment: That sounds pretty reasonable, but don't check the number of people, check for any change. (Since one person may have left and one may have started.)

Comment: Right.. So store the name of each person that was last active, and if the array is different than the current active list, flush all the counters, and start fresh.  And I could still use a random function to get the counters going at first, when they are all empty..  Thanks for the advice, it helped a lot - my mind was stuck, and the answer was actually pretty simple!

Comment: Yeah I think that will work. And you don't even have to store the complete array of current users. Just store the md5 hash of the array. It's just one small string that will change any time any user in the list changes. Very simple to store and compare.